# Need Some Help Parsing JSON with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to parse a JSON document with JQuery, but things just aren't going my way. The feed I want to access is located at "*http://marketplace.envato.com/api/edge/new-files-from-user:collins,themeforest.json*," and here is the return result:

```
{
"new-files-from-user":[
    {
    "thumbnail":"http://3.s3.envato.com/files/60560.jpg",
    "tags":"",
    "user":"collis",
    "url":"http://themeforest.net/item/manilla-photoshop-design/22803",
    "live_preview_url":"http://2.s3.envato.com/files/60561/1_Home.__large_preview.jpg",
    "uploaded_on":"Wed Dec 03 03:32:35 +1100 2008",
    "cost":"10.00",
    "item":"Manilla Photoshop Design",
    "sales":"294",
    "rating":"4",
    "id":"22803"
    },
    {
    "thumbnail":"http://2.s3.envato.com/files/60223.jpg",
    "tags":"clean",
    "user":"collis",
    "url":"http://themeforest.net/item/black-white-simple-theme/22705",
    "live_preview_url":"http://0.s3.envato.com/files/60224/1_home.__large_preview.jpg",
    "uploaded_on":"Tue Dec 02 04:01:12 +1100 2008",
    "cost":"8.00","item":"Black + White Simple Theme",
    "sales":"272","
    rating":"4",
    "id":"22705"
    },
    {
    "thumbnail":"http://1.s3.envato.com/files/44556.jpg",
    "tags":"clean",
    "user":"collis",
    "url":"http://themeforest.net/item/quik-v1-admin-skin/17314",
    "live_preview_url":"http://3.s3.envato.com/files/44557/1_green.__large_preview.jpg",
    "uploaded_on":"Fri Sep 05 07:30:24 +1000 2008","cost":"12.00",
    "item":"Quik v1 Admin Skin",
    "sales":"336",
    "rating":"5",
    "id":"17314"
    },
    {"thumbnail":"http://3.s3.envato.com/files/45212.jpg",
    "tags":"clean",
    "user":"collis",
    "url":"http://themeforest.net/item/freshcorp-business-template/17528",
    "live_preview_url":"http://3.s3.envato.com/files/45213/1_Homepage.__large_preview.jpg",
    "uploaded_on":"Tue Sep 09 06:10:50 +1000 2008",
    "cost":"20.00",
    "item":"FreshCorp - Business Template",
    "sales":"277",
    "rating":"4","id":"17528"
    },
    {"thumbnail":"http://0.s3.envato.com/files/45739.jpg",
    "tags":"clean",
    "user":"collis",
    "url":"http://themeforest.net/item/real-estate-html-template/17732",
    "live_preview_url":"http://0.s3.envato.com/files/45740/1_homepage.__large_preview.jpg",
    "uploaded_on":"Fri Sep 12 14:22:45 +1000 2008",
    "cost":"20.00","item":"Real Estate HTML Template",
    "sales":"175",
    "rating":"4",
    "id":"17732"
    }
]
}
```

I found a premade script that creates a table and adds the JSON items to it (below) but what I'd really like to do is just create my own div with perhaps the image, with the title and a link to the item. I've tried countless tutorials and have also read the JQuery API, I just can't seem to get it to work. Can anyone help me?

```
<table id="userdata" border="1">
    <thead>
        <th>Thumbnail URL</th>
        <th>Item URL</th>
        <th>Cost</th>
        <th>Number of Sales</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>

</table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON(
        "http://marketplace.envato.com/api/edge/new-files-from-user:collins,themeforest.json",
        function(data){
            $.each(data.new-files-from-user, function(i,user){
                var tblRow =
                     "<tr>"
                    +"<td>"+user.thumbnail+"</td>"
                    +"<td>"+user.url+"</td>"
                    +"<td>"+user.cost+"</td>"
                    +"<td>"+user.sales+"</td>"
                    +"</tr>"
                $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
            });
        }
    );
});
</script>
```

Comment: what doesn't work? where is it breaking?

Comment: I don't know where it's breaking. I added brackets to the 'new-files-from-user' property but still nothing works. I'm trying to access the JSON feed and spit out my last items for sale on Themeforest

Answer (score 4):

```
data.new-files-from-user
```

That is malformed javascript right there.  Object properties cannot be accessed like this if they have dashes.  The JS interpreter sees that like this:

```
data.new - files - from - user
```

And of course `data.new` is undefined and `undefined` minus a non existent local variable raises an exception.

Use the `[]` syntax instead.  This allows you to access properties are are not legal for the dot accessor notation.

```
data['new-files-from-user']
```

Comment: Could there be anything else wrong with my code? I put the property in brackets but it still doesn't wanna work: http://jsfiddle.net/2vyfg/

Comment: `data.['new-files-from-user']` != `data['new-files-from-user']`. The Javascript console in any modern browser is your friend.

Comment: I removed the period, now the Chrome console shows 'XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://marketplace.envato.com/api/edge/new-files-from-user:collins,themeforest.json. Origin http://localhost:8888 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.'

Thanks for your continued help thus far

*EDIT:* I think it might be because of the comma in the JSON url, but I'm not sure how to fix it

Comment: That's another issue altogether.  Do you own this server the json is on? If your script is running on a different server enitely, then the remote server either needs to support [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control)  or [JSONP](http://niryariv.wordpress.com/2009/05/05/jsonp-quickly/).  If they allowed CORS this would have worked.  If they allow JSONP then you can change your url to end with `?callback=?`, but they don't seem to support that either.  In other words actually getting this data in the first place probably requires a new question all its own.

Comment: I just tried the JSONP alternative and it returns the JSON feed, but now Chrome is having difficulty with the ':' in the JSON feed

http://i.imgur.com/GQmKA.png

Comment: That's not JSONP...  If it was JSONP it would be wrapped in a callback function.  Click the link in my comment above and read up on how JSONP works.  And if that doesn't clear it up, try a simpler example and make another question.

Comment: Alex, I think I've almost got it figured out. I'm getting the response I wanted, but I'm getting 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :'. Can you please help? http://jsfiddle.net/AWq7D/2/

Comment: The server still isn't returning JSONP... Read my previous comment again, and do some reseach on how JSONP works.  And if you are still confused, gather your facts and make a new question about how to get data via JSONP.  This comment thread is now too long will no longer be seen or replied to, sadly.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call a property by dot notation if it has dashes:

```
data.new-files-from-user
```

A dash is a substraction operator.

Try:

```
data['new-files-from-user']
```

Comment: Is there something else I'm missing? I made your suggested change and it's still not writing to the table http://jsfiddle.net/2vyfg/